# Not able to remove characters from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to loop through a string `x` that represents the alphabet and at the same time compare those values with a list that contains some specific letters.

If there is a match in both the list and the string `x`, it should remove the specific character from the string `x`. It is a very simple and straightforward piece of code. I've followed the `.replace` method to the T. However, when I ran the code, the string `x` still shows up in its original state.

Here is my working code:

```
lettersGuessed = ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']

x = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] in lettersGuessed:
        x.replace(x[i],'')

print x  "Available Letters"
```

Comment: Doing `for i in range(len(x)):` and then `x[i]` is unidiomatic in Python.  Just iterate over the string directly:  `for i in x:`.

Comment: linkfail  XD @user1415571

Comment: Have a look at the documenation for [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Comment: @iCodez, i always forget that you can access strings directly without having to index them.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
x = x.replace(x[i], '')
```

You're not reassigning the changed value back to the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake.

```
x = x.replace(x[i],'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and a generator expression:

```
print("Available Letters","".join(ch if ch not in lettersGuessed else "" for ch in x  ))
```

Using a loop, just iterate over the characters in lettersGuessed and update x each time:

```
 for ch in lettersGuessed:
     x = x.replace(ch,'') # assign the updated string to x


print("Available Letters",x)
```

Or iterating over x is the same logic:

```
for ch in x:
    if ch in lettersGuessed:
       x =  x.replace(ch,'')
```

strings are **immutable** so you cannot change the string in place. You need to reassign x to the new string created with `x.replace(ch,'')`

```
In [1]: x = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'    
In [2]: id(x)
Out[2]: 139933694754864    
In [3]: id(x.replace("a","foo")) # creates a new object
Out[3]: 139933684264296
In [7]: x 
Out[7]: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' # no change     
In [8]: id(x)
Out[8]: 139933694754864 # still the same object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use python sets to achieve this :

```
a = ['a','b','d']
b = "abcdefgh"
print ''.join(sorted(list(set(b) - set(a))))
```

output:

```
cefgh Available letters
```

Or use list comprehensions to achieve this :

```
a = ['a','b','d']
b = "abcdefgh"
print ''.join([x for x in b if x not in a])
```